# Passing function return as parameter to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters, parameter-passing

This code has 2 functions one for taking a list from user and the other one should remove the duplications in this list , it can be done without using functions but im learning functions in Python.
How can I take the list that the user has entered in function `take_list()` and pass it to the function `no_duplication()` ?
when I do it i get this error

> Unresolved reference 'k'

at the line : `no_duplication(k)`

```
def take_list():
    k = []
    i = 0
    list_length = int(input("how many elements your list has ? \n "))
    while i < list_length:
        element = int(input("enter you list elements : "))
        k.append(element)
        i += 1
    print(k, "  is your list")
    return k

def no_duplication(k):
    k = set(k)
    k = list(k)
    print(k, " Your list without duplications")
 

take_list()
no_duplication(k)
```

Comment: `k` is undefined in the last line of your code. You want `k=take_list()` and then `no_duplication(k)`. Or, taken together, you can do: `no_duplication(take_list())`.

Comment: @trincot Thank you ! I didnt know there is such a way .

Comment: @MrXQ, just to avoid confusion - `k` in `k = take_list()` is different variable from `k` used inside the function body. One can use different name if they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign returned value to a new variable and pass that to `no_duplication` as parameter:

```
k = take_list()
no_duplication(k)
```